# scipy sparse matrix access column and row index value

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a `csr matrix` where all the values are `1`. I want to access the first and second element in the tuple that you see when you print the matrix. The first being the user and the second being the item.

I don't understand how I can easily get these elements.

```
  (0, 1)        1
  (1, 0)        1
  (2, 2)        1
  (3, 1)        1
  (3, 2)        1
  (4, 3)        1
  (5, 2)        1
```

```
matrix = [[0,1,0,0],
          [1,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0],
          [0, 1, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Expected outcome:

```
0: 1
1: 0
2: 2
3: 1,2
4: 3
5: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nonzero` method of the `csr_matrix` seems to be what you're looking for.
From the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero):

> *csr_matrix.nonzero()*
>
> Returns a tuple of arrays (row,col) containing the indices of the
>   non-zero elements of the matrix.

So in order to extract your desired information, I suggest creating a dictionary, which easily allows you to continue working with the data. For example this could be done like this:

```
res_dict = {key: [] for key in matrix.nonzero()[0]}
     for row, col in zip(*matrix.nonzero()):
         res_dict[row].append(col)
```

Output for the given matrix is as follows:

```
{0: [1], 1: [0], 2: [2], 3: [1, 2], 4: [3], 5: [2]}
```

Comment: thanks! in the end I used zip: ```row, col = new_matrix.nonzero()
for row, col in zip(row, col):```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Nice, that is more elegant. In fact you can even reduce these two lines to just one: `for row, col in zip(*matrix.nonzero()):`. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [60]: from scipy import sparse                                                                            
In [61]: M = sparse.csr_matrix([[0,1,0,0], 
    ...:           [1,0,0,0], 
    ...:           [0,0,1,0], 
    ...:           [0, 1, 1, 0], 
    ...:           [0, 0, 0, 1], 
    ...:           [0, 0, 1, 0]] )                                                                           
In [62]: M                                                                                                   
Out[62]: 
<6x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [63]: print(M)                                                                                            
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (2, 2)    1
  (3, 1)    1
  (3, 2)    1
  (4, 3)    1
  (5, 2)    1
```

The `rows` attribute of the `lil` format is an object dtype array of lists - one list of indices for each row of the matrix:

```
In [64]: M.tolil().rows                                                                                      
Out[64]: 
array([list([1]), list([0]), list([2]), list([1, 2]), list([3]),
       list([2])], dtype=object)
```

`M.nonzero` returns the `row` and `col` attributes of the `coo` format:

```
In [66]: M.tocoo().col                                                                                       
Out[66]: array([1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], dtype=int32)
In [67]: M.tocoo().row                                                                                       
Out[67]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
```